# Karate.callSingle() function returns [object Object]

Tags: cucumber, karate

Trying to pass git credntials from `config.params` to  download  testdata from git once before everything to used all the features files(testing).

I used `karate.callSingle()` function exeute to `repo.feature` along with argument.

Below is karate-config.js file.

```
        var config={
             URL :  "http://api.com",
             params : {"password":pws, "username":user }
            }

          if( Catg == "_model"){
                var getGit = karate.callSingle('classpath:com/repo.feature', config.params);
                var gitrepo= getGit
            }
```

In `repo.feature` trying to get value of params. Tried lots of ways BUT getting below errors.

```
* print '#{config.params}'
// it returns -- #{config.params}

* def code1 = __arg.params
* print code1 
// it returns -- null

* print params
// it returns error -- params is define 

* print config.params
// it returns error -- config is define
```

Tried to print values in karate-config.js file, then it returns  [object Object]

```
karate.log("******"+ config.params+" ----------")
```

Answer (score 0):

If `* print params` does not work, you must have missed something basic. Please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: when I used       * print params    in other feature file, it works . But it did not work when I used in repo.feature file (ie .feature file called from karate.callSingle() function. ) . please suggest, if

Comment: maybe it is a bug in karate. which is why you need to follow the process, else look for other options please